# Pandas - Breaking data from single row into multiple rows

Tags: pandas

I have a Dataframe that has some customer details (sometimes more than one city mapped to a particular cust_id) in the below format:

```
cust_id, cust_location
1001, id:ref_101
      desc: Chicago, Illinois
      type: city

      id:ref_102
      desc: NewYork, NewYork
      type: city

      id:ref_103
      desc: Saint Joseph, MO
      type: city
1002, id:ref_106
      desc: Chillicothe, MO
      type: city

      id:ref_107
      desc: NewYork, NewYork
      type: city
```

I am trying to break this up such that I get the below structure:

```
cust_id,cust_location
1001, Chicago, Illinois
1001, NewYork, NewYork
1001, Saint Joseph, MO
1002, Chillicothe, MO
1002, NewYork, NewYork
```

In case a particular cust_id has more than one entries it is separated by an empty row as shown in the sample data. I am using pandas 0.23 version so I am unable to use explode option available in version 0.25 onwards

Comment: can you provide the code to make your dataframe?

Comment: What is `print df['cust_id'].head()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution depends of real data - here are 2 columns - first is filled by `cust_id` with whitespaces (or NaNs also working) and in second are another data splitted by `:`:

```
print (df)
   cust_id            cust_location
0     1001               id:ref_101
1           desc: Chicago, Illinois
2                        type: city
3                                  
4                        id:ref_102
5            desc: NewYork, NewYork
6                        type: city
7                                  
8                        id:ref_103
9            desc: Saint Joseph, MO
10                       type: city
11    1002               id:ref_106
12            desc: Chillicothe, MO
13                       type: city
14                                 
15                       id:ref_107
16           desc: NewYork, NewYork
17                       type: city
```

Use [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) with [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) number for replace to missing values and forward filling values by `ffill`, then use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) second column and last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) is used for avoid delete in next step:

```
df['cust_id'] = df['cust_id'].where(df['cust_id'].astype(str).str.contains('\d+')).ffill()
df[['a','cust_location']] = df['cust_location'].str.split(': ', expand=True)
print (df)
   cust_id      cust_location           a
0     1001               None  id:ref_101
1     1001  Chicago, Illinois        desc
2     1001               city        type
3     1001               None            
4     1001               None  id:ref_102
5     1001   NewYork, NewYork        desc
6     1001               city        type
7     1001               None            
8     1001               None  id:ref_103
9     1001   Saint Joseph, MO        desc
10    1001               city        type
11    1002               None  id:ref_106
12    1002    Chillicothe, MO        desc
13    1002               city        type
14    1002               None            
15    1002               None  id:ref_107
16    1002   NewYork, NewYork        desc
17    1002               city        type
```

---

```
df = df[df.pop('a').str.contains('desc')]
print (df)
   cust_id      cust_location
1     1001  Chicago, Illinois
5     1001   NewYork, NewYork
9     1001   Saint Joseph, MO
12    1002    Chillicothe, MO
16    1002   NewYork, NewYork
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am however getting an error `ValueError: Columns must be same length as key` when I try the above code.

Comment: @KevinNash - Can you test `df[['a','cust_location']] = df['cust_location'].str.split(': ', expand=True, n=1)` ?

Comment: it returned an empty Dataframe